# Python logging: display only information from debug level

Tags: logging, python-2.7

For my first logging experiment in Python (2.7) I'm creating a basic logging module, which will quickly create a logger for (so I won't have to configure it per module/class).

What I want to do is to create a logger which displays all messages of level INFO and higher on the console, and moves all DEBUG level information to a text file.

Thus far I have create a logger which prints INFO and up to the console, and which prints every log messages to a text file. However, I don't want all the INFO and higher messages in my text file.

I have made a [Python Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/module-which-creates-loggers-by-name/) which holds my code.

I used the following debug messages from a tutorial:

```
log.debug('All systems operational')
log.info('Airspeed 300 knots')
log.warn('Low on fuel')
log.error('No fuel. Trying to glide.')
log.critical('Glide attempt failed. About to crash.')
```

Which on the console produce:

```
[INFO] root: Airspeed 300 knots
[WARNING] root: Low on fuel
[ERROR] root: No fuel. Trying to glide.
[CRITICAL] root: Glide attempt failed. About to crash.
```

And in my debug_log.txt file:

```
2013-06-14 14:51:46,963:DEBUG:root:All systems operational
2013-06-14 14:51:46,964:INFO:root:Airspeed 300 knots
2013-06-14 14:51:46,964:WARNING:root:Low on fuel
2013-06-14 14:51:46,964:ERROR:root:No fuel. Trying to glide.
2013-06-14 14:51:46,964:CRITICAL:root:Glide attempt failed. About to crash.
```

In the above block, the latter four lines should not be in the file. Is what I'm trying to do possible and how would I get the desired result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to create your own [handler object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#handler-objects).

From the documentation: *The FileHandler class, located in the core logging package, sends logging output to a disk file. It inherits the output functionality from StreamHandler.* So here the idea is to extend the `FileHandler` class, and in the `emit()` method, filter out all `record` objects that are not in the `logging.DEBUG` level.

I have not tested this, but I think it would do the job:

```
from logging import FileHandler, DEBUG

log = logging.getLogger('foo')


class DebugFileHandler(FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False)
        super().__init__(filename, mode, encoding, delay)
    
    def emit(self, record):
        if not record.levelno == DEBUG:
            return
        super().emit(record)

log.addHandler(DebugFileHandler())
```

Of course, you'll have to adapt this code to your code. And, to be honest, `record.level` is a wild guess, but I think it makes sense :-) And, [I got it right](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord)!

In this example, the handler will only be applied for the `foo` logger. You may want to activate it for your main handler, or only for some specific handlers, as you may prefer.

Comment: Here, I was just writing it out :-)

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to look what code works exactly, but with this information I'll get there. :)

Comment: For future references I think it's nice to point out the following:
The above code works mostly. There are some colons missing at the end of the class, but those are easy to spot. If you replace the line `if record.level != DEBUG:` with `if not record.levelno == DEBUG:`, all non-DEBUG logs are filtered out nicely.

Comment: indeed, I misread the documentation, thank you for spotting it, I'm updating my answer

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to create a [filter object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects) and attach it to the handler?

Comment: indeed, that would work out, though I don't think this is appropriate. As a general rule, simpler is better, and you anyway need a `FileHandler` to do the job, so there's no need to add another instance to handle that. And as the documentation you've linked states: `Although filters are used primarily to filter records based on more sophisticated criteria than levels [...]`, i.e. it can do it, but it's been design for more than *just* that.

Comment: Hello, @zmo would you care to answer this question related to this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67460075/12415287