# Python: How do i log requests to multiple files

Tags: python, logging

I'm writing a web-crawler and having an issue, I would like to log each different level of message to its own log file.

I thought this would work but it only creates 'crawler-debug.log'

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='crawler-debug.log')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN, filename='crawler-warn.log')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR, filename='crawler-error.log')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='crawler-info.log')
```

Where am I going wrong here...

Also I would like a time-stamp at the beginning of each line of the log-file so I know when the request was sent.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a file handler for each log level. Formatting can be applied to each handler to add the timestamp. [Python Logging Cookbook - Multiple handlers and formatters](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters)

Also to filter out other log levels other than the one you want (e.g. only DEBUG logging going to debug log file), you'll need to write your own handler object. [See similar question answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108973/python-logging-display-only-information-from-debug-level)

Here's an example with just debug and info logging.

```
import logging

# Define handler to omit logs that are not DEBUG level
class DebugFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False):
        logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)

    def emit(self, record):
        if not record.levelno == logging.DEBUG:
            return
        logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)

# Define handler to omit logs that are not INFO level
class InfoFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False):
        logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)

    def emit(self, record):
        if not record.levelno == logging.INFO:
            return
        logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)


logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handlers
dh = DebugFileHandler('debug.log')
dh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ih = InfoFileHandler('info.log')
ih.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
dh.setFormatter(formatter)
ih.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ih)
logger.addHandler(dh)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
```

Comment: While this link might answer the question, could you summarize the relevant parts in case it gets changed, removed? Thanks.

Comment: Wow this is getting dense, this is almost as many lines of code as my crawler...  I suppose i should create a separate module for logging requests thus separating the logging logic from the crawler logic.

Comment: When I'm done writing the class I will post it here so that others can use and extent it.