# How to Isolate INFO and ERROR logs in its own file path

Tags: django, logging

I have this `LOGGING` settings for my Django app. What I was expecting is that the `views logs` would go into their own separate folder when I have three different `loggers` in my `views` file.

Logger in my `settings` file:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'views_error_file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/errors/views.debug.log',
        },
        'views_info_file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/infos/views.debug.log',
        },
        'views_debug_file': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/debugs/views.debug.log',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'py_folder.views': {
            'handlers': ['views_error_file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },

        'py_folder.views': {
            'handlers': ['views_info_file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },

        'py_folder.views': {
            'handlers': ['views_debug_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    }
}
```

The `views.py` file:

```
import logging
# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def sample_function(request):
    params_choices = ['param_1', 'param_2']

    sample_param = request.POST.get('sample_param')
    # logger.debug should be logged at logs/debugs/views.debug.log
    logger.debug(sample_param)
    if sample_param in params_choices:
        if sample_param == 'param_1':
            # logger.info should be logged at logs/infos/views.debug.log
            logger.info("param_1 okay")
            return redirect("/param_1-req")
        else:
            # logger.error should be logged at logs/error/views.debug.log
            logger.error("param_2 okay")
            return redirect("/param_2-req")
    else:
        logger.error("param does not exist")
            return redirect("/param-invalid")
```

But its only going in to the logs/debugs/views.debug.log.

The `logs/debugs/views.debug.log file`:

```
param_3
param does not exist
```

As you can see, both `logger.debug` and `logger.error` logged to the `logs/debugs/views.debug.log`. I tried changing the `logs/info/views.debug.log` file to `logs/infos/views.info.log` and `logs/error/views.error.log` to `logs/error/views.error.log` but nothing changed.

I don't know why this is the behavior. I am new to Django. Please help.

Comment: Seems like you need to define three different keys. Since all of 3 are `py_folder.views` currently, the last one is the actual valid one. Try changing the keys to unique values.

Comment: What do you mean by key? is it the logger keyword?

Comment: Something like debug_logger, info_logger, and error_logger?

Comment: The keys below `loggers`. They are all `py_folder.views`

Comment: Is that not a file path?

Comment: I think it's just a name.

Comment: Tried changing it, it did not log anything

Comment: Indeed. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49150718/152016 the same problem with your config. Now what isn't clear to me is that if you can leave a single `level: 'DEBUG'` value with multiple handlers (in list as in this answer).

Comment: I did what's in the answer here. It was able to log into the `errors` and `info`, and the `debug` is not logged in the two previous files. But the `info` and `error` are still going on all the files. It only filtered the `debug`.

Comment: Well that's the way log is done in python, right ? info level data is contained in debug level info.

Comment: I cannot isolate the `info` and `error` in its exclusive file path?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109663/152016

Comment: I keep trying the one above. I keep getting this error: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'`. If I put a default value, it creates it immediately. I am completely lost

Comment: See my answer, tested on latest django version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've come up with something.

Inside your app (in this example it's the `polls` app from tutorial), create a directory `logs`, and inside it a file named `handlers.py`, with this content:

```
from logging import FileHandler, INFO, ERROR, DEBUG

class AppFileHandler(FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, loglevel, mode, encoding, delay):
        super().__init__(filename, mode, encoding, delay)
        self.loglevel = loglevel
    
    def emit(self, record):
        if not record.levelno == self.loglevel:
            return
        super().emit(record)

class AppDebugFileHandler(AppFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False):
        super().__init__(filename, DEBUG, mode, encoding, delay)

class AppErrorFileHandler(AppFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False):
        super().__init__(filename, ERROR, mode, encoding, delay)

class AppInfoFileHandler(AppFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=False):
        super().__init__(filename, INFO, mode, encoding, delay)
```

Then change `LOGGING` as this:

```
import os # you can move this import to beginning of settings.py

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'views_info_file': {
            'class': 'polls.logs.handlers.AppInfoFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'views.info.log'),
        },
        'views_error_file': {
            'class': 'polls.logs.handlers.AppErrorFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'views.error.log'),
        },
        'views_debug_file': {
            'class': 'polls.logs.handlers.AppDebugFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'views.debug.log'),
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'polls.views': {
            'handlers': ['views_info_file', 'views_error_file', 'views_debug_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
    }
}
```

This will create 3 log files on root of your project (not app, you can customize the `filename` directory).

This works, but perhaps it's not the best way, may be reinventing the wheel here. Also the `level: 'DEBUG'` setting no longer indicates the error level logging, this should be stressed in a comment on settings.

Comment: This worked!!! only its putting the file on the root directory, not on the logs folder I created.

Comment: Is it because of the BASE_DIR? should I add something more here?

Comment: nevermind. I added this `PY_ROOT = 'py_folder'`

`LOGGING_ROOT = os.path.join(PY_ROOT , 'logs')` and used it istead of `BASE_DIR`. Thanks so much

Comment: Yes you can put something like `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/polls/logs/views.error.log')`, then in my example it would put the logfile inside the same dir as the `handlers.py`.